# What is the C++20 ""_a= doing?

Tags: c++, c++20

In [std::format in C++20](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/std-format-in-c-20):

```
"name"_a=name, "number"_a=number);
```

What is the <kbd>""_a=</kbd> doing?

Comment: They are [user-defined literals.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Comment: Named arguments are not in C++20, as the post notes, nor even in C++23.  The argument id has to be numeric.  Maybe this is some implementation-specific extension?

Comment: This is the "named argument" syntax from [libfmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html#format-api).  Note that this syntax did *not* get added to C++20 - the linked article is incorrect.

Comment: @0x5453 Well, the linked article *does* explicitly mention that named arguments are not in C++.

Answer (score 4):

`""_a` is a user defined literal.

In this context it would help you create the equivalent `arg("name", value)` by writing it as `"name"_a = value`.

However the named arguments didn't make it into the standard so this is not part of the standrd lib. You could still write it if you really wanted to.